# Show that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : E \times E \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $E$ a normed vector space, where the norm is induced by a dot
>   product. The norm of $E \times E$ is defined as $||(x,y)|| = \max\{||x||,||y||\}$. Show that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : E \times E \to \mathbb{R}$ is a
>   continuous function.

I know my question is strange, but I can't show continuity. I know we can't subtract two dot products, and it troubles me a lot to prove.  Does anyone could help me at this level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix $(x,y)\in E \times E$. Let $\epsilon>0$. 
$$|\langle x',y'\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle |=|\langle x+(x'-x),y+(y'-y)\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle|$$

We can rewrite the inner product as
\begin{aligned}&=|\langle x, y+(y'-y)\rangle +\langle (x'-x),y+(y'-y)\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle|\\
&=|\langle x,(y'-y)\rangle +\langle x,y\rangle +\langle (x'-x),y\rangle +\langle (x'-x),(y'-y)\rangle -\langle x',y'\rangle|\\
&=|\langle x,y'-y\rangle+\langle x'-x,y\rangle +\langle (x'-x),(y'-y)\rangle|\end{aligned}
Then, using the Triangle inequality and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$|\langle x,y\rangle -\langle x',y'\rangle|\leq ||x||||y-y'||+||x-x'||||y||+||x-x'||||y-y'||$$

So, since we can take $\delta$ s.t. $||(x',y')-(x,y)||<\delta$ to make $||y-y'||$ and $||x-x'||$ arbitrarily small, we can find a $\delta$ to make the right hand side less than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $E_1, E_2, F$ are vectors space and $B:E_1\times E_2\to F$ is bilinear map such that $B(x, \cdot): E_2\to F$ and $B(\cdot,y):E_1\to F$ are linear continous maps, for every $x\in E_1$ and $y\in E_2$, then $B:E_1\times E_2\to F$ is a continous map.

For prove that, your need basically of the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem.

Comment: I can't use this theory for a simple analysis course